# Assigning variables using switch case

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, switch-statement

i need to use the variables that is assigned in switch case for my stored procedure but i always get unexpected results .please help..any reply would be a great help.thanks.

```
private void CheckMessage()
        {
            string chk = null;
            ShortMessage l = new ShortMessage();
            string strCommand = "AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"";
            objShortMessageCollection = objclsSMS.ReadSMS(this.port, strCommand);
            foreach (ShortMessage msg in objShortMessageCollection)
            {

                l.Message = msg.Message;
                string[] splt = l.Message.Split('#');
                for (int i = 0; i < splt.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] parts = splt[i].Split(':');
                    char prefix = Convert.ToChar(parts[0]);
                    string value = parts[1];

                    switch (prefix)
                    {
                        case 'T':
                            l.truck = value;
                            break;
                        case 'D':
                            l.driver = value;
                            break;
                        case 'R':
                            l.receiveby = value;
                            break;
                        case 'A':
                            l.arrivedate = value;
                            break;
                        case 'U':
                            l.unloaddate = value;
                            break;
                        case 'N':
                            l.deliverynote = value;
                            break;
                        case 'L':
                            l.deliverydate = value;
                            break;
                        case 'S':
                            l.deliverystatus = value;
                            break;
                        case 'M':
                            l.mac = value;
                            break;
                        case 'C':
                            l.msgcreatedate = value;
                            break;
                    }

                }
                chk = l.getINFO(l).Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

                if (chk == "1")
                {

                    this.AutomaticReply();
                    this.DeleteToSim();
                }
                else
                {

                    this.DeleteToSim();
                }

                l = null;
            }


        }
        #endregion
```

here is my stored procedure..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Message_Check]
    @truck nvarchar(20),
    @driver nvarchar(20),
    @deliverynote int

AS
    BEGIN
         SELECT 1 FROM Truck trk, Driver drv, DeliveryNotes dnt
                           WHERE trk.Plate_Number = @truck
                             AND drv.DRIVER_ID = @driver
                             AND dnt.DNID = @deliverynote
                             AND dnt.Status = 'N'
    END
```

Comment: What are the "unexpected results"

Answer (score 1):

Your query will give output 1..... always

```
SELECT 1 FROM Truck trk, Driver drv, DeliveryNotes dnt
                           WHERE trk.Plate_Number = @truck
                             AND drv.DRIVER_ID = @driver
                             AND dnt.DNID = @deliverynote
                             AND dnt.Status = 'N'
```

It should be

```
SELECT Top 1 * FROM Truck trk, Driver drv, DeliveryNotes dnt
                           WHERE trk.Plate_Number = @truck
                             AND drv.DRIVER_ID = @driver
                             AND dnt.DNID = @deliverynote
                             AND dnt.Status = 'N'
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the character you're looking at isn't a capital, or you might be getting a leading space.  See if something like this helps:

```
char prefix = parts[0].Trim().ToUpper()[0];
```

If you still have problems, edit your original post and add the structure of the ShortMessage class

Answer (score 0):

Please use Break Points and Debug by Checking the values that are passed to stored procedures.
values may have Extra space like "aa  bb   " Trim the end values using **`TrimEnd(' ');`** function, & Please **Parse** correctly to its Data types (`Int , Double , DateTime etc`).the sms you are reading and utilizing  for other things. Please check the call is **Private / Public** so as to reach its values to stored procedures.

```
char prefix = Convert.ToChar(parts[0]);
```

use

```
parts[0]=parts[0].ToUpper();
char prefix = Convert.ToChar(parts[0]);
```

keep Trying...